# mechanism of method reference and collect stream method

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-stream, collect

I'm studying on java functional interface recently and wondering how does method reference work specially on [**collect stream method**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiConsumer-java.util.function.BiConsumer-).

On the java documentation, collect method gets 3 parameters : **supplier**, **accumulator** and **combiner**.

```
collect(
        Supplier<R> supplier, 
        BiConsumer<R,? super T> accumulator, 
        BiConsumer<R,R> combiner
)
```

.. and this is sample code.

```
 List<String> asList = stringStream.collect(
       ArrayList::new,     // suplier?
       ArrayList::add,     // accumulator?
       ArrayList::addAll   // combiner?
 );
```

So, my questions are these :

1. type of parameter

   As you can see in the code above, collect method receives BiConsumer interfaces as a parameter for accumulator and combiner.

   However, the ArrayList::add and ArrayList::addAll methods take a single parameter(not "Bi", It's "Unary"!).

   I wonder how this code is possible. Is there any hidden mechanism for this?
2. purpose of combiner

   I wonder what the purpose of combiner is.

   I understood that collect method create a mutable collection from an existing collection using a suplier and an accumulator.

   But it's hard to understand where combiner is needed in this process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For non static method references, the Object (in your case `ArrayList instance`) is also passed as a parameter. So the `BiComsumer` will be called as shown.

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
BiConsumer<List<Integer>, Integer> v1 = List::add;  // method reference
BiConsumer<List<Integer>, Integer> v2 = (a,c)->a.add(c); //lambda
```

They are both called like this.

```
v1.accept(list, 10);
v2.accept(list, 20);
System.out.println(list);
```

Prints

```
10, 20
```

In the case of the combiner, that is only used to combine multiple lists when they are created in different threads when parallel streams are involved.

Comment: [Here](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3453296/get-started-with-method-references-in-java.html#:~:text=An%20unbound%20non%2Dstatic%20method,example%20is%20String%3A%3AtoLowerCase%20.) is one I found in Infoworld.